# Android Resources store object

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to define a class that contains some data

Id : Int
Value1 : String
Value2 : String

then I want to define an array of that class and store some static data in it, Can I use resource files in android to define these static data ?

please if that is possible let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Most often you just put this kind of stuff in an XML file (in res/xml) and read it like a normal XML file.

Comment: Depending on the size of the data, it can also sometimes be sensible to use the Assets directory. Just depends on what you are trying to do.